# comma-separated input displayed in another div prior to submission

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to allow users to input multiple id #'s separated by commas in an input field. I want to then take that input, separate the data by comma's and insert them into separate `<li>` tags to display in another div, (for verification purposes), prior to submitting. Here is what I have so far...please be gentle...I've not had to do this before.

```
if ($("#" + prodID).find("input.text").val() == value) {
   $("#" + prodID).find("input.text").val("");
}
```

This is where I am so far and don't know where to go from there. I believe that I will need to add `replaceWith()` to the end of `.val("");` but am not sure. If there are examples I can look at I'm sure I can figure this out.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Here is the HTML. (sorry I missed it at first)

```
<div id="selCodes">
<p>Your selected codes <span><a href="#">Clear</a></span></p>
  <ul>
      <li><!--inserted by clicking "okay"-->
          Some Account - 0123<a href="#" title="delete"><img alt="delete" src="imgs/delete.png"></a>
      </li>
  </ul>
  <button id="subCodes">Submit</button>
</div><!-- /#my-selections -->

<h4>Narrow results by</h4>

<div id="prodId">
  <a href="#">Item code</a>
    <span><a href="#">Clear</a></span>        
    <p>Choose item from dropdown. Type code or codes, (separated by comma), and click the add button to create filters.</p>
        <select id="code-type">
            <option>Prod code</option>
            <option selected="selected">Prod UPC</option>
            <option>Master UPC</option>
            <option>CC</option>
        </select>            
        <input type="text" value="" />  
        <button>OK</button>
</div>
```

I have a funny feeling I'm way off-base.

Comment: The code in your question doesn't match the question ! the code is comparing 2 values (`val() == value`) ... and the question is about getting a comma separated value and creating `li` elements ... perhaps you could show us the current HTML and the expected HTML output once the script has run

Comment: Can you show your html as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nta5Y/)

Here's the code:

```
$('#separate').on('keyup',function(){
   var splitter = $('#separate').val().split(',');  
   var htmlToAdd='';
   for (i=0; i<splitter.length; i++)
   {
       htmlToAdd += '<li>'+splitter[i]+'</li>';
   }
   $('#results').html(htmlToAdd);
});​
```

I used your html in my demo, with a slight modification of adding an id on the input box and adding a validation result div at the bottom.

Comment: very nice...the only problem I have is that the codes need to go up into the top div when the "okay" button is pressed. The validation is done after they confirm that list.

Comment: I'm faced with a problem where the button needs to be clicked twice in order for the function to fire...what could be causing that?

Comment: Not sure to be honest without seeing the code.  Do you have a fiddle or snippet at least of it?

Comment: Not yet no...sorry. Weird request...what if I needed to take that splitter[1] array and use the info in it to populate another area of the html? For instance it's been requested that the values be used as ID's for each <li>. If the number that was split was 98765 then the ID for the <li> would be the same. Can we use info from one array for another?

Comment: I assume you just mean like 

`htmlToAdd += '<li id='+splitter[i]+'>' + splitter[i]+'</li>';`

Comment: Just figured out I can...with an associative array using .each() right?

Comment: ROTFLOL...I'm sorry. You're right...it's that easy. What threw me was that they are using a different variable name for the ID and since "splitter" is a different variable I thought I had to do something super complex. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute matching with `[value=somevalue]`
Instead of writing this

```
if ($("#" + prodID).find("input.text").val() == value) {
    $("#" + prodID).find("input.text").val("");
}
```

`$("#" + proID + " input:text[value="+value+"]").val('');`

Check the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ranganadh/vjq4w/)

Answer (score 0):

This assumes you want to update anytyime the input value changes, and that your verification `ul` has an id of `verify`:

```
$('#'+prodId).find('input:text').change(function(e){
   var $this = $(this),
       value = $this.val(),
       values,
       $verify = $('ul#verify'),
       verifyHTML = '';
   if(value) {
       if (value.indexOf(',') != -1) {
         values = value.split(',');
       } else {
         values = [value];
       }

       for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
         verifyHTML += '<li>'+values[i]+'</li>';
       }

       $verify.html(verifyHTML);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming from the text within the question you mean something like this (there is no checking here just displaying the values - I may be way off what you require) ->

```
$(function() {
    $('input[type=button]').click(function() {
        var inputs_to_check = $('#check').val();
        var array_to_check = inputs_to_check.split(',');
        $.each(array_to_check,function(index,value) {
            $('#output').append('<li>' + value + " = " + $('#'+value).val() + "</li>");
        })
    });
});​
```

this takes some text from an `input` (`#check`) - which contains a comma separated list of `id`s of `input` elements to check. It then splits the value and loops over them (`$.each()`) and then creates `li` elements containing the `id` of the `input` checked and its `value` (`.val()`)

The HTML looks like this :

```
inputs :<br>
<input id="test1" value="1234"/><br>
<input id="test2" value="5678"/><br>
Output to check : <input id="check"/> <input type="button" value="check"/>
<div>
    <ul id="output"></ul>
</div>​
```

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/XXnNC/)

Comment: Actually, I was hoping that the user could put multiple codes in the one input text box like so "code1, code2, code3" and then have that display in the div.

Comment: @Amidude thats exactly what the code does - in my example enter `test1,test2` and click `check` - it will output a `li` containing the id of the input followed by its value

Comment: Thanks so much for the help everyone...the only problem I'm having now is that the button requires 2 clicks to work.

Comment: @amidude what code are you using ??? Either add it to your question or create a http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you mean:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7WcAg/)

html:

```
<input id="input1" />
<ul id="ul1"></ul>​
```

jquery:

```
$('#input1').on('keyup', function() {
    var textIn = $(this).val();
    var idArr = textIn.split(',');
    $('li', '#ul1').remove();
    $.each(idArr, function(i) {
        $('#ul1').append('<li>' + idArr[i] + '</li>');
    });
});​
```

Comment: That's it. Wow...can't believe I was so far off. I appreciate the help. I need to read more.